# Extension icons are missing once it is being uploaded to Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to upload my first Google Chrome extension, but I have a strange issue.

My manifest file is as follows:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Chat About",
  "description": "Chat about the content of the web page you're currently visiting with other visitors.",
  "version": "0.0.1.1",

  "icons":
  {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },

  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions":
  [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

The content of the source directory is as follows:

```
icon.png
icon128.png
icon16.png
icon32.png
icon48.png
manifest.json
popup.html
popup.js
```

The unpacked extension icons appear, as shown here:

[image]

But as I'm trying to upload it to Chrome Web Store, the icons are missing, as shown here:

[image]

I couldn't find any solution to this issue. I have no idea what's wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This icon uploaded separately in the Developer Dashboard.

[image]

Be noticed that this icon should be drawn with following rules
(see [Supplying Images](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images#icons)):

> The actual icon size should be 96x96 (for square icons); an additional 16 pixels per side should be transparent padding, adding up to 128x128 total image size.

**Update #1: June 2020**

The setting is still available in the old dashboard.
You may go back from the new dashboard by clicking to "opt out" link in the bottom left corner:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't it suppose to extract it from the zip file? How is the manifest file useful then?

Comment: @Moon No, it doesn't extract from zip. Icons from the manifest are shown on a client's extensions page.
While an icon that you upload in the dashboard is shown only on the webstore site.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Web store [help documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons) mentions about adding icon in manifest file which will be used on web store. _Add new icon_ seems to be a workaround and feels like overriding manifest icon. Is someone able to display icon on dashboard through manifest?

Comment: [App Icon](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images#icons) documentation also mentions providing app icon within zip file.

Comment: This is no longer supported in the new Chrome Web Store. All icons must be in the extension's ZIP file and referenced from the manifest. Otherwise, the extension seems to get rejected. From the [v2 changelog](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQi3OH0AE53rgDO1DSSRqLdH0h7790hPKiIHGlayLfhDGyEZWZLmxBQVNuSE4JFR3uj3fjRGY2lOK2J/pub): "In the new dashboard, you can no longer upload icons from the UI. In order to change the icon of your item, you must upload a new package with the new icon included in the package."

Comment: FYI - as of June 2020 I tried listing icons in the manifest and nothing was appearing but I clicked on the link to go to the old dashboard and uploaded an icon manually and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

My extension also got rejected because the Chrome Web Store couldn't find its icons. When loading the unpacked extension in development mode in Chrome, everything worked fine.

It seems like the Web Store is confused by paths that start with `./`. The following `manifest.json` was rejected:

```
{
    // ...
    "icons": {
        "48": "./icons/icon-48.png",
        "128": "./icons/icon-128.png",
        "512": "./icons/icon-512.png",
        "1024": "./icons/icon-1024.png"
    }
}
```

The following worked:

```
{
    // ...
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon-128.png",
        "512": "icons/icon-512.png",
        "1024": "icons/icon-1024.png"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the size of the 128px icon was wrong. I had to check again the dimensions of all icons (16,32,48,60,128) and upload zip again, with this I was able to solve it.

But I think the old dashboard is a good solution and the new one doesn't have it.